How do I make postgres use an index when the query condition references a subquery?
I have a table 'analytics_event' (with 9.7M rows) which I need to query for records 'created' after a given time. The table has various indexes which are being ignored in favour of a seq scan over the table. I've distilled the problem down to the following queries.
This query doesn't use the index (takes around 40s):
explain with batch_params as (
  select 
    (now() - '1 minute'::interval)::timestamptz as created
) select * from private.analytics_event
  where
    created > (select created from batch_params);

-- output --
Seq Scan on analytics_event  (cost=0.01..1620760.63 rows=3251510 width=1025)
  Filter: (created > $0)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)

Whereas this query DOES use the index (CTE kept, although useless) (takes a less than a ms):
explain with batch_params as (
  select 
    (now() - '1 minute'::interval)::timestamptz as created
) select * from private.analytics_event
  where
    created > (now() - '1 minute'::interval)::timestamptz;

-- output --
Index Scan using analytics_event_payload_event on analytics_event  (cost=0.44..7.33 rows=1 width=1025)
  Index Cond: (created > (now() - '00:01:00'::interval))

My index and table are as follows:
CREATE TABLE private.analytics_event (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    environment_id varchar NOT NULL,
    payload jsonb NULL,
    created timestamptz(3) DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT analytics_event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (environment_id, id)
);

CREATE INDEX analytics_event_payload_event ON private.analytics_event USING btree (created, ((payload ->> 'foobar'::text)));

In original larger query, the batch_params queries a specific cursor table for those values.
I've tried:

Adding a limit 1 on the CTE expression (no difference).

Wrapping the batch_params in a function (no difference) e.g.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_created_date() RETURNS timestamptz AS $BODY$ 
  select created from cursor_table;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL stable


Wrapping the whole query in a function which has a declared variable created. The function first selects the value into the variable before querying the analytics table. This used the index, however it's much less maintainable, and its annoying that I can't explain analyze the query any more (since it's wrapped in a function).


A workaround I think, is to just use a transaction in my host application with multiple intermediate queries however I'd like to avoid this if possible.
How can I restructure this to utilise my index while still keeping my params dynamic?
Postgres Version: 15.6
Edit with explain:
explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) ... <the slow query with sub-query>.
-- output --
Seq Scan on private.analytics_event  (cost=0.01..1620760.63 rows=3251510 width=1025) (actual time=52571.409..52571.410 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: analytics_event.id, analytics_event.environment_id, analytics_event.payload, analytics_event.created
  Filter: (analytics_event.created > $0)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9798348
  Buffers: shared hit=473037 read=1025792
  I/O Timings: shared read=49404.088
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: (now() - '00:01:00'::interval)
Settings: effective_cache_size = '7959688kB', jit = 'off', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Query Identifier: -2998777079014550499
Planning Time: 0.087 ms
Execution Time: 52571.433 ms


explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) ... <the fast/indexed query with inline condition>
-- output --
Index Scan using analytics_event_payload_event on private.analytics_event  (cost=0.44..7.33 rows=1 width=1025) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: id, environment_id, payload, created
  Index Cond: (analytics_event.created > (now() - '00:01:00'::interval))
  Buffers: shared hit=3
Settings: effective_cache_size = '7959688kB', jit = 'off', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Query Identifier: -1698698247486258523
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=5
  I/O Timings: shared read=3.082
Planning Time: 3.208 ms
Execution Time: 0.023 ms


Rel Size of the index is 214M.
The last_autoanalyze was run today (the data was added a over a long period prior).


Could you please share the result from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement?

The current index could be rather large because of the second column in this index. How big is it? And did you try an index on just the timestamp? And what about the statistics, when did analyze its last job?

I've added some more information. Thanks @FrankHeikens.

The PostgreSQL optimizer is not smart enough to pull up the subquery, so you should do it yourself:
WITH batch_params AS (
  SELECT current_timestamp - '1 minute'::interval AS created
)
SELECT *
FROM private.analytics_event
   CROSS JOIN batch_params
WHERE analytics_event.created > batch_params.created;


This is the answer - thank you Laurenz!
(Sorry I don't yet have enough points to upvote your response)

is it possible to have batch_params come from a source table?
Your solution works however I've now run into an issue where if I select batch_params from a source table (e.g. analytics_cursor with a single row), again the index isn't utilised. Do you have any ideas if it's actually possible to have dynamic params selected from a source table (or does the problem keep getting pushed back)?

That would be a problem, because PostgreSQL doesn't know at query planning time what the result from the other table will be, so it won't know that there are few result rows and an index scan is best. If you know that the time interval is small, perhaps you can AND the condition with one like above that tells the optimizer enough to choose the index scan.

Thanks again Laurenz.
For anyone else who sees this, I ended up wrapping they query in a PL/pgSQL function. I first queried and assigned my params into a couple of variables, then ran my main query using those variables as params. The index was used as I'd seen before - I could tell this due to the run time, however there might be other ways of digging into that.

This helped me understand that I had to manually pull up a sub-CTE in my query in order to get the index working! Hoist!
